# Express js - async pending

Tags: node.js, express, node-async

i'm trying return data to view from multiple selects and i'm using the `async.parallel` but in console show me Promise `{<pending>}` .
I require the `var async = require('async');`

This is the first time that i try use it, what i'm doing wrong?

```
 new(req, res)
  {
    async.parallel(
    {
      one: function(callback) {

        callback(null, request.query("SELECT * FROM table1 where ref like '90%'"));
      },
      two: function(callback) {

        callback(null, request.query("SELECT * FROM table2 where ref like 'K%'"));

      }
    }, function(err, results)
    {
      console.log("RESULT:");
      console.log(err);

      return res.render('view-1', {"one": results.one, "two": results.two});
    });
  }
```

Thank you

Comment: The reason for the console shows you 'pending', is because the promise is never resolved or rejected

Comment: How can i do that? thank you @R.Gulbrandsen

Comment: request.query, which library are you using?

Comment: var connection = require('../db/config');
var mssql = require('mssql');
var request = new mssql.Request(connection);
@R.Gulbrandsen

Comment: Which module is `request` in your case? I have doubt on the way you are calling callback. `callback(null, request.query("SELECT * FROM table1 where ref like '90%'"));`

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark: Try to change from callbacks to Promises

```
var request1 = new request.query("SELECT * FROM table1 where ref like '90%'");
var request2 = new request.query("SELECT * FROM table2 where ref like 'K%'");

return Promise.all([request1, request2]).then(function(listOfResults) {
    return res.render(...);
}).catch(function(err) {
    // ... query error checks 
});
```

The Promise.all's then will only be fired if both queries are successfull and the list of the results will be in the same order as the queries.

If you're not using ES6 then you can import Promise like this

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
```